# Implementation of two legged OAuth 2.0 for WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api, two-legged

I created a mvc4 webapi project using VS2012RC. I tried to implement two legged Oauth 2 in my project. I followed the tutorial  "http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/03/18/oauth-2-0-for-mvc-two-legged-implementation.aspx", even though it is for mvc i am implementing it for web api. But isn't working

I created a html page for my client side. When the html page load it executes an ajax function which is intended to return "access Token".

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = 'http://localhost:9792/api/Login';
            $.get(url, function(data) {

            alert(data);
            }, "jsonp");
        });
        </script>
```

**The server side code is,**

```
[NoCache]
public class LoginController : ApiController
{

    public LoginModelOAuth GetLogin()
    {

        var response = OAuthServiceBase.Instance.RequestToken();

        LoginModelOAuth lmo = new LoginModelOAuth();
         lmo.RequestToken = response.RequestToken;

        return lmo;
    }
```

}

**RequestToken()** method look like,

```
    public override OAuthResponse RequestToken()
    {
        var token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        var expire = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        RequestTokens.Add(token, expire);

        return new OAuthResponse
        {
            Expires = (int)expire.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds,
            RequestToken = token,
            RequireSsl = false,
            Success = true
        };
    }
```

**LoginModelOAuth** model look like,

```
public class LoginModelOAuth
{

    public string RequestToken { get; set; }      


    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

When i execute the client side code i receive following error

```
"500 Internal Server Error"
```

So i debugged server side code and in server side I got an error corresponding to this code

"var response = OAuthServiceBase.Instance.RequestToken();" , and the error is

```
  NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

My webconfig file look like,

```
  <configuration>
  <configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="oauth" type="OAuth2.Mvc.Configuration.OAuthSection, OAuth2.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
<sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
  <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
  <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
</sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
   <oauth defaultProvider="DemoProvider" defaultService="DemoService">
    <providers>
      <add name="DemoProvider" type="MillionNodesApi.OAuth.DemoProvider, MillionNodesApi" />
    </providers>
<services>
  <add name="DemoService" type="MillionNodesApi.OAuth.DemoService, MillionNodesApi" />
</services>
  </oauth>
    <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="OAuthAuthentication"     type="OAuth2.Mvc.Module.OAuthAuthenticationModule, OAuth2.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
     <pages>
     <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
 <dotNetOpenAuth>
    <messaging>
      <untrustedWebRequest>
    <whitelistHosts>
      <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
      <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
    </whitelistHosts>
  </untrustedWebRequest>
</messaging>
<!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
<reporting enabled="true" />
```

Will it work for web api?

If not, please suggest me any tutorial that would help.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share your web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are in [IIS7 with integrated mode so you will need to migarate your config](http://bhaidar.net/post/2007/09/13/HttpModules-and-IIS-7.aspx) from system.web/httpModules to system.webServer/modules

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
       <add name="OAuthAuthentication"     type="OAuth2.Mvc.Module.OAuthAuthenticationModule, OAuth2.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
    </httpModules>
```

Becomes

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="OAuthAuthentication"     type="OAuth2.Mvc.Module.OAuthAuthenticationModule, OAuth2.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
```

**Try also**

You could try getting the module to be hit by setting this

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

**Or Perhaps**

If you are still having issues it may be the execution order of the modules try remove the routing one and put your OAuth one at the top...

```
<modules>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
<add name="OAuthAuthentication"     type="OAuth2.Mvc.Module.OAuthAuthenticationModule, OAuth2.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" preCondition="" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
```

Comment: I am getting the Request token on client side.But when i post, i got the error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:9792/api/Login. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.". I could solve this issue before but now cross domain is not working along with authentication. I used the following tutorial to solve CORS "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/07/02/cors-support-in-asp-net-web-api-rc-version.aspx".

Comment: @Kishore I think you have a new problem which probably warrants another question but you can try adding this into your web config 
<system.webServer><httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I modified the web config file, but i got an error "Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.". I posted a question about this error here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409600/error-request-header-field-content-type-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow