# Error :Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, cors

I created an mvc4 web api project using vS2012. I used following tutorial to solve the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/07/02/cors-support-in-asp-net-web-api-rc-version.aspx". It is working successfully, and i post data  from client side to server successfully.

After that for implementing Autherization in my project, I used the following tutorial to implement OAuth2, "http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/03/18/oauth-2-0-for-mvc-two-legged-implementation.aspx". This is help me for getting RequestToken on client side.

But when i post data from client side, i got the error,
     **"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."**

My **client side** code look like,

```
 function PostLogin() {
    var Emp = {};            
    Emp.UserName = $("#txtUserName").val();             
    var pass = $("#txtPassword").val();
    var hash = $.sha1(RequestToken + pass);
            $('#txtPassword').val(hash);
    Emp.Password= hash;
    Emp.RequestToken=RequestToken;
    var createurl = "http://localhost:54/api/Login";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: createurl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(Emp),
        statusCode: {
                200: function () {
                $("#txtmsg").val("done");                       
                toastr.success('Success.', '');                         
                }
                },
        error:
            function (res) {                        
                toastr.error('Error.', 'sorry either your username of password was incorrect.');            
                }
        });
    };
```

My **api controller** look like,

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public LoginModelOAuth PostLogin([FromBody]LoginModelOAuth model)
    {
        var accessResponse = OAuthServiceBase.Instance.AccessToken(model.RequestToken, "User", model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe);

        if (!accessResponse.Success)
        {
            OAuthServiceBase.Instance.UnauthorizeToken(model.RequestToken);
            var requestResponse = OAuthServiceBase.Instance.RequestToken();

            model.ErrorMessage = "Invalid Credentials";

            return model;
        }
        else
        {
            // to do return accessResponse

            return model;
        }

    }
```

My **webconfig** file look like,

```
 <configuration>
   <configSections>   
   <section name="entityFramework"    type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="oauth" type="MillionNodes.Configuration.OAuthSection, MillionNodes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
  <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
  <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
  <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<oauth defaultProvider="DemoProvider" defaultService="DemoService">
<providers>
  <add name="DemoProvider" type="MillionNodes.OAuth.DemoProvider, MillionNodes" />
</providers>
<services>
  <add name="DemoService" type="MillionNodes.OAuth.DemoService, MillionNodes" />
</services>
</oauth>
<system.web>
 <httpModules>
   <add name="OAuthAuthentication" type="MillionNodes.Module.OAuthAuthenticationModule, MillionNodes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
  </httpModules>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />      
  <modules>
      <add name="OAuthAuthentication"     type="MillionNodes.Module.OAuthAuthenticationModule, MillionNodes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" preCondition="" />
 </modules>
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
<dotNetOpenAuth>
<messaging>
  <untrustedWebRequest>
    <whitelistHosts>
      <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
      <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
    </whitelistHosts>
  </untrustedWebRequest>
</messaging>
<!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
<reporting enabled="true" />
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027705/error-in-chrome-content-type-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-headers and add another rule in your web config

Comment: Hi are you testing this js directly from your browser and local file system e.g. file:// URL.?? And from which browser?

Answer (score 179):

As hinted at by this post [Error in chrome: Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027705/error-in-chrome-content-type-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-headers) just add the additional header to your web.config like so...

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It tried this but i got error,  "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54/api/Login. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: @Kishore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: I am still having no luck with this, i have posted in detail here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437748/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 121):

It is most likely due to a **cross-origin request**, but it may not be.  For me, I had been debugging an API and had set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`, but it appears that recent versions of Chrome are requiring an extra header.  Try prepending the following to your file if you are using PHP:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Make sure that you haven't already used `header` in another file, or you will get a nasty error.  See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more.

Comment: Why doesn't the asterisk cover everything - -;

Comment: @user2483724 that's because the asterisk allows any Origin domain, but it doesn't specify which additional headers are allowed. It just says, 'you're able to call this script from a page running somewhere else'

Answer (score 18):

I know it's an old thread I worked with above answer and had to add:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
```

So my header looks like:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
```

And the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 13):

For Nginx, the only thing that worked for me was adding this header:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';
```

Along with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
```

Then reloaded the nginx config and it worked great. Credit https://gist.github.com/algal/5480916.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem, while differently from other answers in my case I use ASP.NET to develop the WebAPI server.

I already had Corps allowed and it worked for GET requests. To make POST requests work I needed to add 'AllowAnyHeader()' and 'AllowAnyMethod()' options to the list of Corp options.

Here are essential parts of related functions in Start class look like:

**ConfigureServices method:**

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                          builder =>
                          {
                              builder
                                  .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                                  //.AllowCredentials()
                                  ;
                          });
    });
```

**Configure method:**

```
        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

Found this from:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- https://forums.asp.net/t/2168883.aspx?Request+header+field+content+type+is+not+allowed+by+Access+Control+Allow+Headers+in+preflight+response+

Comment: Doesn't CORS allow the Content-Type header by default though?