# Why did this http request fail and succeed at the same time?

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm trying to send a PUT request and I get this:

[image]

Strangely, when I click on this it shows me a 200 OK. I also see that the headers allow everything so I don't see why it's telling my PUT is not allowed.

[image]

I have a separate question detailing the angular aspect of the app here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467052/is-this-usage-of-ngresource-correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Error :Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409600/error-request-header-field-content-type-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow)

Very strange fix, on the server side I had to change:

`response.setHeader("*");`

to

`response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");`

For some reason the asterisk doesn't cover "content-type"