# Using AJAX with Random.org in MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, random

I'm having trouble getting a number from Random.org.  I am following their API, and I believe I have constructed the request correctly.  Here is the request code:

```
self.GetResults = function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json-rpc; charset=utf-8",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                    "method": "generateIntegers",
                    "params": {
                        "apiKey": "Get-a-free-one-at-the-site",
                        "n": 1,
                        "min": 1,
                        "max": 20
                    },
                    "id": 1
                }

            })
            .done(function (data, status, request)
            {
                alert("Success! " + data[0]);
            })
            .fail(function (request, status, error)
            {
                alert("Failed " + error);
            });
        }
```

The problems I am having are as follows:

1. If I don't include `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` then the default type is `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"`, per the jQuery API documentation.  Random.org states in their API that they require a JSON request (application/json-rpc specifically, but application/json is acceptable).  I therefore get a parse error in response.
2. If I do include the content type mentioned above, I get the error, "Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

I have tried to add code to the web.config to allow the request header as follows:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

From this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/12413863/981202, but have had no luck.

I've also tried modifying the Global.asax as follows:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
}
```

As in another Stack Overflow post (I don't have the link), but that didn't seem to do it either. For clarity, I put this function after the Application_Start() function.

You may be wondering why I don't just use the Random class.  The reason is because I'd like to use Random.org if nothing else then as an exercise.  I'd like to find a solution to this problem if one exists.  Previously, I had some data here that indicated that the C# Random class didn't do a very good job, but I was corrected, so that data has been removed.  Yes, the Random class is an option, though as I mentioned, I'd like to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation you read on random.org? I'm looking at http://www.random.org/clients/http/, and based on what I'm seeing there, all you need to do is request the following url: http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=20&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new. Also, even though System.Random isn't truly random, it seems that out of tens of thousands of trials, you'd see a nicer distribution than that.

Comment: can you show the where you implemented the C# random class?  Running my own tests generates a much more straight line than yours, using the same data.

Comment: @ pmcoltrane: The Random.org documentation I'm reading is here: https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/ Specifically here: https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/introduction and here (under generateIntegers: https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/basic

Comment: @Jonesy: I'll do my best to show you.  The Counter class is simply a switch statement that increments a number by 1 each time it's generated.
if (response == 'y')
   {
    while (DateTime.Now < end)
    {
     Random rand = new Random();
     int randomInt = rand.Next(1, 21);
     counter.Count(randomInt);
    }
   }  So you can see how I'm getting the random numbers here, which I hope is what you were looking for.  :)

Comment: You should instantiate Random one time, outside of the loop. `Random rand = new Random();` creates a new instance of Random using the system timer as its seed value. By calling it inside of a loop, you're probably seeding it with the same timer value repeatedly. See the remarks for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx. (I'll have to look over the json-rpc docs that you linked.)

Comment: @pmcoltrane: Thanks!  I wrote the program I got the data from quite some time ago.  I made the change you suggested and re-ran it just now, and I get a much better distribution.  I'd still like to use Random.org, and if I can't, I guess the Random class is a much more viable option than I had previously thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I have added this code to my web.config. At first I put it in the `<configuration>` node and it did not work. Then I realized that it should be within the `<system.webServer>` which is also within the `<configuration>` node. Once I put it there it worked and I did not receive the error mentioned again.