# How to load ajax data into DIV without using .get() or .load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have been given a URL by a partnering company to load content into a DIV. We put the following onto a page:

```
<div id="catalog"></div>
```

And then use `.get()` to put content into it. A problem arises due to the fact that we're using jQuery 1.3.2 on some of the older sites, and the engineering department is not going to update that any time soon. Both `.get()` and `.load()` are giving me errors.

I tried things such as:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $.ajax("http://appserv.ourpartneringcompany.com/catalog/?acct=12345",function(data){
            $('#catalog').html(data);
         });
});
```

The error goes away, but the data doesn't load. Could I use `jQuery.ajax()`?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/load/ , http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/

Comment: If you change the "html()" to "text()", does that work?  Is anything coming back in the data?

Comment: The .load() method was added on jquery version 1.0 so it should be available on your jquery 1.3.2. What errors are showing up with the `.get()` or the `.load()`

Comment: @JorgeF The error is "XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

Comment: Im not an expert but I think thats because you are trying to get some data from another server. Maybe this answer will help you understand better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think jQuery 1.3.2 supports that syntax.

Try modifying to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://....",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data){
    $('#catalog').html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked on a test page, but it did not work on our sites. I received this error in the Chrome console: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

Comment: Thats another issue, server related I believe. See this post for potential fixes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409600/error-request-header-field-content-type-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow