# Create Item by using Item web api

Tags: sitecore

I want to know how implement javascript method to create new item by using sitecore  item web api.I am trying for below code my self.

But in the browser console show this error:
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myproject/-/item/v1/sitecore/Content/Home?name=MyItem5&template=Sample/Sample%20Item&sc_database=master. Request header field X-Scitemwebapi-Password is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.**

Please can anyone help me!!!!!!!

```js
function createItem(){
jQuery.ajax({
crossDomain: 'true',
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://myproject/-/item/v1/sitecore/Content/Home?name=MyItem5&template=Sample/Sample Item&sc_database=master',
dataType: 'JSON',
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

     headers:{
     "X-Scitemwebapi-Username":"sitecore\\Admin",
     "X-Scitemwebapi-Password":"b",
    },


success: function(data) {

    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
},
error: function(res, error){
alert(JSON.stringify(res))
    alert(res+ ' something is wrong');
 }
```

});
}

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have these settings in your `Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config`

```
itemwebapi.mode="StandardSecurity"
itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks golden grahams.I tried for your suggestion.But it is not like security configuration issue.seems like  issue of cross domain or header request.

Comment: Ok, was worth a shot. Another thing to try - Add the headers to the list of custom headers. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409600/error-request-header-field-content-type-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow

Comment: golden grahams,  Thanks for ur kindly reply.Still I am in trouble.

Comment: request states 200.It means request successful but issue with authentication for sitecore.