# How to make a simple JSON POST with custom header

Tags: jquery, json, post

I'm trying to make a simple JSON POST with custom header like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://oe.com/social/identity/auth/bydeviceid/AZERTYD',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

I receive the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I've also noticed that my code is sending a `OPTIONS` request and not POST even I mentioned a `POST` request. How do I solve this?

Comment: Might be duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409600/error-request-header-field-content-type-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow

Comment: Try fixing the typo "applicaiton" to "application" and you can mention the content type this way, contentType: "application/json"